# How to match everything before a pattern, until reach another pattern

Tags: python, regex, match

With Python regex, I'm trying to match everything before a pattern (including line breakers), until reach another pattern.
This is the Text:

> DFGC
> 2836 -07-0411B
> IMUD - DHI211 (MOOYEHBF P/
> SHDUF)
> C7000039694 (PD MOFIBD PODF
> BAOJFD)

The code below matches everything before "C700" pattern. I need everything before "C700", BUT limited to "IMUD" (including it). So, the result should be "IMUD - DHI211 (MOOYEHBF P/
SHDUF)"

```
(?s)^.+?(?=C700\d*(?=\s))
```

See it in regex101: [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/wtRD1L/1)

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos to nice question(which has efforts/code and samples of input; keep it up), please do add samples of output also in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Try `^[A-Z]{4} -.*?(?=\s*C700\d*\s)` with `m`, `s` and `i` flags. See https://regex101.com/r/wtRD1L/2. Or, another suggestion: `(?mi)^\w+ - \w+\s*\([^()]*\)(?=\s*C700\d*\s)`. Please provide exact pattern requirements, not just what you want to match.

Comment: Could you clarify the requirements please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple regex to do this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(IMUD .*?)(C700)', flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Explanation:

- The first group `(IMUD .*?)` captures everything after IMUD in a *non-greedy* way (means it stops capturing when the 2nd capturing group, `(C700)` is found
- we use the flag `re.DOTALL` so that the `.` also match new lines `\n`

To get what you want, only retrieve the *first group* matched

```
s = """DFGC 2836 -07-0411B
IMUD - DHI211 (MOOYEHBF P/ SHDUF)
C7000039694 (PD MOFIBD PODF BAOJFD)"""

res = pattern.search(s).group(1)
res
>>> 'IMUD - DHI211 (MOOYEHBF P/ SHDUF)\n'
```